# Comment dit-on "... see what ... can do" en français ?

Tags: traduction, formulation-idiomatique

Pour être précis, je veux assurer une personne que je l'aiderai. En anglais, on dit "I'll see what I can do". Comment le dit-on en français le plus naturellement ?

Comment: Je ne suis pas vraiment assuré qu'une personne m'aidera si elle me dit *I'll see what I can do*.

Comment: je ne vois de "see to" dans la phrase example

Comment: Please note: "to see to something" in English is different that "see what one can do". Please edit the question. What do you actually mean?

Comment: @jlliagre This can be said very honestly. So, what you say just sounds sarcastic and I guess people think that is funny.

Comment: @Lambie Il n'y a rien de sarcastique dans mon commentaire. Ce n'est ni moqueur, ni personnel, ni méchant. J'indique simplement mon opinion sur le décalage entre ma compréhension de l'anglais et celle de l'OP. Cette opinion semble partagée par d'autres personnes. Il n'y a même pas d'intention d'être drôle, je ne comprends pas comment tu peux imaginer ça.

Comment: @Aravind If you missed my initial comment, there is a serious mismatch between *assurer une personne qu'on l'aidera* and the straight translation of "I'll see what I can do" to French (*Je vais voir ce que je peux faire*). If someone says to me "*je vais voir ce que je peux faire*", I usually think it's likely doomed. There is zero commitment in that sentence.

Comment: @jlliagre I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a une méprise dans votre texte ; la construction verbale dans le titre (**see to it that**) correspond bien à l'idée de donner l'assurance qu'un action sera accomplie ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/see-to-it-that)), mais ensuite vous passez dans le texte de la question au verbe « *to see* » ; ce n'est pas le même.

I

Supposons que l'expression verbale dans le titre est "*see*".

On utilise pour cela le même verbe qu'en anglais dans une construction de futur proche, mais comme en anglais, il n'exprime pas l'assurance d'une aide et seulement l'assurance que s'il y a quelque chose de possible, alors ce sera fait.

- **aller voir**
- Nous allons voir ce que nous pouvons faire pour que vous obteniez cette bourse.
- Elle va voir ce qu'elle peut faire pour que votre commande soit prête plus tôt.

II

Supposons que dans le corps du texte vous aviez écrit "I'll see to it that something gets done.". Cela exprime l'assurance que quelque chose sera fait. Il y a plusieurs façons de rendre ce sens en français.

- **veiller à ce que**  ([gymglish](https://www.gymglish.com/fr/gymglish/traduction-anglais/see-to-it-that))

  - Je vais veiller à ce que les paiments soient faits régulièrement.
- **faire en sorte que + subjonctif** ([gymglish](https://www.gymglish.com/fr/gymglish/traduction-anglais/see-to-it-that))

  - Je ferai en sorte que le travail soit terminé à l'heure.
- **faire en sorte de + infinitif**

  - Je ferai en sorte de terminer  le travail à l'heure.
- **assurer qqn que** (*plus fort que "see to"*)

  - Nous vous assurons que tout notre possible sera fait.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I misunderstood your query. https://www.linguee.com/ and https://context.reverso.net/ may be helpful for issues like this. For instance:

> Leave the papers with me and I'll see what I can do. Laisse-moi les papiers et je vais voir ce que je peux faire.

Comment: > je vais voir ce que je peux faire. 

I did see this translation on Google Translate but was wondering if it made sense. Thank you.

Comment: @AravindSuresh That's the right translation.